# (Error: 30004) Message blocked. The destination number you are trying to reach is blocked from receiving this message

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

i got this message while i am trying to send sms with twilio. i never blocked any number

Answer (score 4):

In my case it happened for an Indian number. For Indian number it could be blocked by the end user -

> Limitations sending SMS messages to Indian mobile devices
>
> SMS messages entering into India are categorized as “Transactional” or “Promotional” and may result as an "Error - 30004".
>
> By default, all SMS messages sent from Twilio phone numbers are categorized as “Promotional” and are subject to the following limitations:

They cannot be sent to any phone number in India’s Do Not Call Registry

> If you’ve been having trouble sending SMS messages to an Indian number, see if that number is registered on the [National Do Not Call Registry](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/search.misc).
>
> If the owner of the phone number wishes to start receiving SMS messages from Twilio, they can update the DNC settings by following the instructions [on this website](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/).

More details : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices

Comment: will this issue get resolved if I buy a phone number from Twilio?

Comment: I have no problems with bought twilio numbers. That error can appear once for the first sms, then it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Error 30004](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30004) doesn't mean that you blocked a number, but that the number you are trying to send to has blocked messages from your number. They could have done so by [texting "STOP," "CANCEL" or other particular words to your number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-).

If you don't believe that this has happened, then I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with the number that is causing this error and they will look into it.

Comment: If the owner of the number has blocked messages from you then the only thing you can do is to encourage them via another channel to opt in again by texting START to your number. If they haven’t blocked you, then like I said you should get in touch with Twilio support.